# How to make divs re-arrange when another div is positioned between existing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Here is code and fiddle.

CSS

```
 #siirto {display: none}

 #container {
 width:90px;
 height:200px;
 border:2px; 
 border-style:solid;
 margin-left: auto ;
 margin-right: auto;
 background-color:#999;

 }

 .luokka {
 position:relative;
 float:left;    
 width:20px;
 height:20px;
 margin:2px 2px 2px 2px;
 border:2px;
 border-style:solid;
 background-color:#3F0;
 }

 .luokka1 {
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 width:80px;
 height:0px;
 margin:2px 2px 2px 2px;
 border:0px;
 border-style:solid;
 background-color:#00F;
 }
```

HTML

```
 <div id="container">
 <div id="siirto" class="luokka1"></div>
 <div id="1" class="luokka" onclick="siirra('1', '20', '20')"></div>
 <div id="2" class="luokka" onclick="siirra('2', '20', '20')"></div>
 <div id="3" class="luokka" onclick="siirra('3', '20', '20')"></div>
 <div id="4" class="luokka" onclick="siirra('4', '20', '20')"></div>
 <div id="5" class="luokka" onclick="siirra('5', '20', '20')"></div>
 <div id="6" class="luokka" onclick="siirra('6', '20', '20')"></div>
 <div id="7" class="luokka" onclick="siirra('7', '20', '20')"></div>
 <div id="8" class="luokka" onclick="siirra('8', '20', '20')"></div>
 <div id="9" class="luokka" onclick="siirra('9', '20', '20')"></div>
 <div id="10" class="luokka" onclick="siirra('10', '20', '20')"></div>
 <div id="11" class="luokka" onclick="siirra('11', '20', '20')"></div>
 <div id="12" class="luokka" onclick="siirra('12', '20', '20')"></div>
 </div>
```

SCRIPT
     function siirra(idnumero, kokox, kokoy) {

```
    x=$("#" + idnumero).position();
    var toppi = parseFloat(x.top)+parseFloat(kokoy)+parseFloat(6);

 if ($("#siirto").height() <= 1) {

 $("#siirto").css("top", toppi);
 $("#siirto").fadeIn();
 $("#siirto").animate({height:'40px',opacity:'0.4'},"fast");
 $("#siirto").animate({width:'89px',opacity:'0.8'},"fast");
 $("#siirto").animate({opacity:'1.0'},"fast");

 }

    else if ($("#siirto").height() >= 1) {  
    $("#siirto").animate({width:'40px',opacity:'0.8'},"fast");
    $("#siirto").animate({height:'0px',opacity:'0.4'},"fast");
    $("#siirto").animate({opacity:'1.0'},"fast");
    $("#siirto").fadeOut();


      }
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SuSDL/9/

When green cubes are clicked it show and reposition "siirto" div. Idea is that it positions below clicked div and pushes green cubes below clicked one to below blue "siirto" div. I cannot get it working, there is something big that i am missing.

If i change

```
 .luokka1 {
 position:absolute;
```

it works as planned, but does not push divs below siirto downwards (of course), otherwise it looks as should.

How do i proceed from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want. But you can use `insertBefore` to push the elements down. Because the elements are not grouped however, this pushes every individual element down.

```
$(".luokka").click(function(){
        if ($("#siirto").height() <= 1) {
        $("#siirto").insertBefore($(this));
        $("#siirto").fadeIn();
        $("#siirto").animate({height:'40px',opacity:'0.4'},"fast");
        $("#siirto").animate({width:'89px',opacity:'0.8'},"fast");
        }
else{
    $("#siirto").animate({width:'40px',opacity:'0.8'},"fast");
        $("#siirto").animate({height:'0px',opacity:'0.4'},"fast");
        $("#siirto").fadeOut();
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SuSDL/12/

If you want to push down the elements as a row you have to group them in a div and insertBefore the parent:

Updated HTML

```
<div class="containThree">
    <div id="1" class="luokka"></div>
    <div id="2" class="luokka"></div>
    <div id="3" class="luokka"></div>
</div>
```

Added jquery:

```
$("#siirto").insertBefore($(this).parent());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SuSDL/13/

UPDATE:
If you want the rows to stay intact during the animation you're easiest sollution is to remove the width animation:

`$("#siirto").width("89");`

http://jsfiddle.net/SuSDL/15/

UPDATE FOR ROWWIDTH:
You can use the following code to check for row width:

`var rowWidth = $(this).parent().width();`

Updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/SuSDL/17/

Comment: This is almost what i am looking for. I think grouping divs might be the best solution. The problem with insertBefore is that it goes "front side" of div that is clicked and pushes the pressed link down. If i put insertAfter it pushes next links down but i want to keep every row if green blocks intact so then i would have to calculate to insertAfter in correct position but i have another size blocks also, for here they are all 20x20 but i have also 40x20, 60x20...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "stay intact"? The rows are staying intact in my current example right? The are not intact during the animation, is that what you are refering to?

Comment: Yes, they do. I was referring to insertAfter without grouped divs. I think this might solve my problem, i just need to develop way to calculate row widths because of different widths of green blocks in final code but that is not a problem. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Check the last update that calculates the row width of the container div.

Comment: @Jarno
Please consider accepting the answer if this fixed your problem.
Kind regards